# Escaping PowerShell within Ansible

Tags: python, powershell, ansible, escaping, win-shell

I need to run the following command with ansible

```
Set-remotemailbox Test.User -emailaddresses @{Remove="Test.User@test.e-test.net"}
```

I have the following code for Ansible

```
  vars:
    _name: Test.User

  tasks:
 
    - name: Set Default Email Address For User
      ansible.windows.win_shell: |
        Set-remotemailbox "{{ _name }}" -emailaddresses @{Remove=\`"'{{ _name }}'@test.e-test.net\`"}
```

I am following the powershell recommended escaping in this document

https://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShellEscape.htm

Ive tried using win_powershell but the issue seems to be the escaping the Ansible variable and the escaping of the double quotes after the @Remove keyword. Has anyone achieved this or had similar experiences please?

Comment: What happens with the current code? Do you get specific errors or messages in the Ansible logs indicating what the resulting string/script actually looks like?

Comment: One way I've worked around this previously is to pass the Ansible variables into the task as environment variables and read then from there inside the PowerShell script - that way you don't have to worry about escaping the Ansible variable to make it work as a string literal when it's replaced verbatim into the Ansible token inside the PowerShell code. I don't have access to my code right now, but I can post an answer later if no-one else does first, or see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_environment.html for a pointer...

Comment: That would be super helpful @mclayton

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen get a 'changed' but its not implemented, here's the ouput ```{
  "start": "2024-01-18 09:45:22.571065",
  "stdout": "Set-remotemailbox ‘test.user -emailaddresses @{Remove=\\\”’test.user’@e-test.net\\\"}\r\n",
  "cmd": "\"Set-remotemailbox ‘test’.user -emailaddresses @{Remove=\\`\”’test.user’@.e-test.net\\`\"}\"",
  "stderr": "",
  "changed": true,
  "rc": 0,
  "delta": "0:00:00.281995",
  "end": "2024-01-18 09:45:22.853061",
  "stdout_lines": [
    "Set-remotemailbox ‘test.user -emailaddresses @{Remove=\\\"'test.user’@.e-test.net\\\\"}"
  ],```

Comment: Note also, you've got 2 different Ansible variables referenced in your powershell  - ```{{ __name }}``` (two underscores) and ```{{ _name }}``` (one underscore) - is that correct, or a typo?

Comment: @mclayton typo, fixed as removed real names and domains for posting online

Comment: fixed by using powershell natively 

```
vars:
  _joined_name: test.user  tasks:    
- set_fact:
        _email: "{{ _joined_name }}@test.net"    

- name: Set Default Email Address For User
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: |
          $username = '{{ _joined_name }}'
          $email = '{{ _email }}'
          Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn
          Set-remotemailbox $username -Emailaddresses @{Remove="$email"}
```